# On expansion of a disc due to heating, why doesn't a hole form in the centre?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

Been provided that on expansion, the hole in a similar disc whose center has been cut out expands, what happens to a disk without hole under similar temperature conditions and why so? Consider the disks to be uniform.

Comment: Did you actually think about the answer, or did you copy and paste your homework?

Comment: Yes.I actually thought about..but not sure.If in a disk with hole cut out,  we integrate in form of rings and assume same rate of expansion , the hole expands. However it may not be so in case of another disk.

Comment: What happens if you cut a hole in the middle of the disk, then put the cut out piece back in the hole, then heat it up?

Comment: won't it expand a similar way as a disk without been operated like this(i.e cutting hole and puting it back)?

Comment: there won't be a hole formed.But why so? or is it formed at molecular level? Or stresses are developed anyway? I can't get to the most probable reason.

Comment: Why won't there be a hole formed between the two rings? The outer ring gets bigger, making its hole bigger, so what fills up the hole?

Comment: the cut out piece had been placed back before heating(as you said)and it expands to fill up the hole. So it could be concluded that the expansion is uniform in this case. Thanks.But even if it so, won't the integral rings go on expanding uniformly with a minute hole at center but the hole cannot be formed because of the ring with near to zero radius ?

Comment: You can cut up a disc into a disc and a ring. No matter how many times you do this, you still have a disc in the middle.

Comment: I guess there will be a hole if thermal stress is more than its tensile limit or precisely it would break else it can expand its radius within certain range

Comment: @user253751 Thanks! I really appreciate your effort to make me think rather than approach a direct answer!

Comment: @Anusha Thanks! I got this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each ring of matter within the disk expands by the same factor.  As the circumference of a ring approaches zero, so does the expansion.

Comment: @ R.W.Bird Thanks! I got this.